How can the maximal ideal space of the Fourier Stieltjes algebra be non-separable?
I have been asking a fair few (probably elementary) questions about abstract harmonic analysis lately. By means of explanation, I am just feeling around the subject at the moment and trying to build up some intuition for familiar examples. It is easy to find very long and dense works that deal with the subject in full generality. Harder to find works that deal with specific examples.
The Fourier-Stieltjes algebra $F(\mathbb R)$ of $\mathbb R$ is the set of all functions of the form
$$x \mapsto \int e^{-i \lambda x} d \mu(\lambda)$$
as $\mu$ ranges over the set of finite Borel measures. The product is pointwise multiplication.
Bochner's theorem says this algebra is ismorphic to the space of measures with convolution as the product.
The Gelfand spectrum $\sigma F (\mathbb R)$ is the set of multiplicative linear functionals $F(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb C$ equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence.
Now $F (\mathbb R)$ is contained in the algebra  $C_b(\mathbb R)$ of all bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$. The Gelfand spectrum of $C_b(\mathbb R)$ is the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta \mathbb R$. It contains a copy of $\mathbb R$ with each $x \in \mathbb R$ corresponding to the evaluation functional $f \mapsto f(x)$. These functionals comprise a dense open copy of $\mathbb R$ inside $\beta \mathbb R$. This can be proved from the explicit construction of the topology on $\beta  \mathbb R$ using ultrafilters. Identify that copy with $\mathbb R$.
By Gelfand Duality the inclusion map $F(\mathbb R) \to C_b(\mathbb R)$ induces a continuous surjection $S: \beta \mathbb R \to \sigma F( \mathbb R)$. Since $\mathbb R$ is dense and open it gives a countable dense set $D \subset \beta \mathbb R$. The image $S(D)$ is then dense in $\sigma F (\mathbb R)$ and so $\sigma F (\mathbb R)$ is separable.
This all sounds fine by me. The problem is that this paper has proved the Gelfand space of the algebra of measures is not separable.
I am not looking for someone to explain the paper to me. I am looking for someone to point out whatever obvious mistake I have made above to conclude $\sigma F (\mathbb R)$ is separable.
Would anyone please have the time to enlighten me?

I'm not a functional analyst, but here's a guess: Theorem 11 in the linked paper says $\Delta(M_0(G)$ isn't separable. But $M_0$ contains only those measures whose Fourier-Stieltjes transform vanishes at infinity. Your countable dense set probably consists of point mass measures at the rational numbers, and the Fourier-Stieltjes transforms of those measures don't vanish at infinity. (What I actually know is that, although $\beta\mathbb R$ is separable, $(\beta\mathbb R)-\mathbb R$ isn't.)

@AndreasBlass Wouldn't the inclusion $M_0(G) \to M(G)$ induce a map $\Delta(M(G)) \to \Delta(M_0(G))$? Then the range not being separable would imply the domain is not either?

@AndreasBlass Looking further at the paper only makes me more confused. They talk about $\Delta(M(G)))$ for $G$ a compact group. By my reasoning that should just be $G$ itself. But there it is.

@an_ordinary_mathematician $\beta \mathbb R$ contains $\mathbb R$. The latter is separable so the former is also separable.

I assume the map $\beta\mathbb R\to\Delta(F(\mathbb R))$ you discuss is induced by restricting functionals $\varphi\in C_b^*$ to $F\subseteq C_b$. But then I don't understand why this map is surjective. That would mean that each multiplicative functional on $F$ has a multiplicative extension to $C_b$, but why is that so?

@ChristianRemling I think the proof works something like this. Gelfand duality says we can treat $F(\mathbb R)$ as $C_b(Y)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $Y$. Namely $Y = \Delta(F(\mathbb R))$. Also by Gelfand duality the map $M:C_b(Y) \to C_b(\beta X)$ comes about from some continuous map $m: \beta X \to Y$ and that $M$ has the form $f \mapsto f \circ m$. If $m(\beta X) \ne Y$ then we can choose any function $m(\beta X) \to \mathbb R$ and extend it two different ways to two different functions $f_1,f_2$ on $Y$. But then we have $f_1 \circ m = f_2 \circ m$ contradicting injectivity of $M$.

@Daron: Thanks for clarifying, so that was not it. One more attempt: What is the norm on $F(\mathbb R)$? The two candidates are $|\mu|$ (total variation norm) and $|\widehat{\mu}|{\infty}$, and I think in both cases there are potential problems with the argument. If we use the total variation norm, then the inclusion map $F\to C_b$ is not isometric, and if we use $|\widehat{\mu}|{\infty}$, is $F$ actually complete then?

@ChristianRemling I think it must be the total variation norm. I don't think we need the map of Banach algebras to be an isometry to apply Gelfand duality. I think we just need it to be  a homomorphism that commutes with the complex conjugate.

@Daron: Actually, with the total variation norm (and the involution $f^=\overline{f}$), this is not a $C^$-algebra, so is not isomorphic to $C(\Delta_F)$ and nothing seems clear anymore. (Somehow I assumed it was a $C^*$-algebra until a few minutes ago, so most of what I wrote earlier cannot be taken very seriously.)

@Daron: To try to take something away from this, I suspect that if you just try to write out your argument for the separability of $\Delta_F$ with all the details and full definitions included, it will collapse. It is sometimes tempting to take short-cuts, but it is also only too easy to go astray this way (I speak from personal experience here).

@ChristianRemling I think the difficulty for me is that I originally learnt the duality for real-valued functions and I am overlooking how when things become complex, you need to modify the morphisms to not only be complex-linear, but also respect conjugation.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Daron In constructing the mapping $S$, you seem to assume that the embedding $F \rightarrow C_b$ is continuous. Why is that?

I have been too busy to write a proper response but these comments (and the original question) indicate some fundamental misconceptions about Banach algebras, without getting into the precise technicalities of Fourier-Stieltjes algebras. It is absolutely, fundamentally, irrevocably, utterly not the case that a semisimple CBA can be idetified with $C_b(Y)$. What people handwave away as "Gelfand duality" is a very precise theorem whose hypotheses are not met here. I strongly recommend reading through the construction of the Gelfand transform in something like Kaniuth's CBA book.

BTW the "I originally learned the duality for real-valued functions" is not really relevant. The problem is not the complex scalars, the problem is that for Banach algebras of functions the Gelfand transform need not have closed range, so it won't surject onto $C_0(X)$ (and certainly won't surject onto $C_b(X)$) when $X$ is the maximal ideal space. Thinking of commutative semisimple Banach algebras as if they all look like $C_b(X)$ is going to lead to trouble.
